# Forward application's console output to Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, console, serilog, fluentd

I have Elasticsearch and Kibana running in docker containers on my computer.

Is it possible to redirect console output from my C# .NET application to the Elasticsearch?
I am using Serilog and I know how to configure appsettings to forward logs directly to the Elasticsearch. But it is not what I need. I am wondering if it is possible to forward console output to the Elasticsearch without changing application ot its config?

I found this article [Writing logs to Elasticsearch with Fluentd using Serilog in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/writing-logs-to-elasticsearch-with-fluentd-using-serilog-in-asp-net-core/) saying that Fluentd might do what I want. I just don't understand how to properly configure td-agent.conf.

```
 <source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match es.**.*>
  @type forest
  subtype elasticsearch
  <template>
    host localhost
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix ${tag}
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </template>
</match>
```

Or am I on the wrong path here anyway?